# gdb syntax of numbers

Tags: assembly, gdb, hex

I'm learning Assembler and this is my problem.

When i use gdb i see the registers with the following syntax for the number on HEX:

```
 Dump of assembler code for function return_input:
 0x000000000040053d <+0>:   push   %rbp
 0x000000000040053e <+1>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
 0x0000000000400541 <+4>:   sub    $0x20,%rsp
 0x0000000000400545 <+8>:   lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 0x0000000000400549 <+12>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
 0x000000000040054c <+15>:  callq  0x400440 <gets@plt>
 0x0000000000400551 <+20>:  lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 0x0000000000400555 <+24>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
 0x0000000000400558 <+27>:  callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
 0x000000000040055d <+32>:  leaveq 
 0x000000000040055e <+33>:  retq   
 End of assembler dump.
```

But i wanna see them with the following syntax:

```
(gdb) disas return_input
Dump of assembler code for function return_input:
0x080483c4 <return_input+0>:    push   %ebp
0x080483c5 <return_input+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080483c7 <return_input+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x080483ca <return_input+6>:    lea    0xffffffe0(%ebp),%eax
0x080483cd <return_input+9>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080483d0 <return_input+12>:   call   0x80482c4 <_init+40>
0x080483d5 <return_input+17>:   lea    0xffffffe0(%ebp),%eax
0x080483d8 <return_input+20>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x080483dc <return_input+24>:   movl   $0x8048514,(%esp)
0x080483e3 <return_input+31>:   call   0x80482e4 <_init+72>
0x080483e8 <return_input+36>:   leave
0x080483e9 <return_input+37>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
```

I'm using Arch Linux with an Intel processor 64-bit. The first code is from 64-bit and the second one from 32-bit.

I really do not anderstand why now is "-0x20" and is not "0xffffffe0"? Or why "sub $0x28,%esp" change to "$0x20,%rsp".

Thank you for your time. I will really appreaciate any answer.

Comment: If you meant to expand [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877696/different-gdb-registers-names), please edit it instead of posting a new one

Comment: `0xffffffe0` is the same as `-0x20` when viewed as a signed value, but `-0x20` is easier to read. And you shouldn't really compare those two code snippets since one is 64-bit and one is 32-bit.